# pandas dataframe as field in django

Tags: python, arrays, django, pandas

I want to add pandas dataframe (or a numpy array) as a field in django model. Each model instance in django has a large size 2D array associated with it so I want to store it as numpy array or pandas dataframe.

please guide me how can I achieve it. I tried below but it doesn't work.

```
from django.db import models
import numpy    
class datafile(models.Model)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    data = numpy.array((1000,1000))
```

I am reading data from excel file and setting it to data variable in views.py but after I save the model, the value for data doesn't get updated.
regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're likely gonna want to use a [PickleField](https://github.com/gintas/django-picklefield) to store your numpy or Pandas dataframe.  The PickleField will serialize the data into a text field for the database storage and convert it back upon retrieval.

```
from django.db import models
from picklefield.fields import PickledObjectField
import numpy

class DatafileModel(models.Model)
    data = PickledObjectField()
```

And then just create or manipulate your model instances with numpy or pandas objects:

```
datafile = DatafileModel()
datafile.data = numpy.array((1000,1000))
datafile.save()
```

Comment: Will there be significant performance difference between this `PickledObjectField` and django provided PostgreSQL `JSONField()` ?

Answer (score 5):

In order not to create a necessity to create model instances separately one could use the following simple approach

```
import pandas as pd
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class StoredDataFrame(Model):
    data = JSONField()

    @classmethod
    def putframe(cls, dataframe):
        storeddataframe = cls(data=dataframe.to_json(orient='split'))
        storeddataframe.save()
        return storeddataframe

    def loadframe(self):
        return pd.read_json(self.data, orient='split')
```

Sample use:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=list('qwerty'), columns=list('ABCD'))
    storeddata = StoredDataFrame.putframe(df)
    retrieveddataframe = storeddata.loadframe()
```

Comment: A nice solution that doesn't rely on third party package, thanks!

Comment: django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField is deprecated. Support for it (except in historical migrations) will be removed in Django 4.0. HINT: Use django.db.models.JSONField instead.

Comment: in your example `self.data` will return a Dict not a json string. `pd.read_json()` expects a string (or file or buffer)

Answer (score 4):

Late to the discussion here, but if you're using PostgreSQL you could leverage it's JSON support via django_pgjsonb and convert back-and-forth between the DataFrame and JSON representations of the content.

Something like this should work (you'll need to play with the 'orient' parameter):

```
import pandas as pd
from django_pgjsonb import JSONField


class MyModel(models.Model):
    dfjson = JSONField()

    @property
    def store_dataframe(self, dataframe):
        self.dfjson = dataframe.to_json()

    @property
    def load_dataframe(self):
        return pandas.read_json(self.json)    

my_instance = MyModel()
my_instance.store_dataframe(df)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))
my_instance.store_dataframe(df)
my_instance.save()
new_df = my_instance.load_dataframe()
#hopefully new_df and df are equivalent
```

https://github.com/yjmade/django-pgjsonb
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: currently all the postgres fields are available from django.contrib.postgres.fields (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/)

Comment: Will there be significant performance difference between  `PickledObjectField` (in accepted answer) and Django provided PostgreSQL `JSONField()` ?